# Activity could not be loaded TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

I have created a custom activity for XAML build in TFS 2012. The activity can be seen in the toolbox, and can drag and drop to the XAML build definition file. This is possible when i open the custom activity project in the visual studio along side with the XAML file.

But if i open the build definition file alon in VS the custom activity throws the error and comes in a red box.

Am i missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's to be expected. When you open the xaml file alone, it doesn't have a reference to the custom activity and will show an error but it doesn't mean that it is broken.

When you add your custom activity to the "Custom Assemblies" folder in source control the build process will find it and the build should complete successfully.

Have a look at the docs for the [Community TFS Build Extensions](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20extensions%20into%20a%20build%20template&referringTitle=Documentation)  as they show the steps for consuming custom activities.